# Unable to Pass UUID string to API endpoint using POSTMAN Correctly

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, postman, django-urls, uuid

The API endpoint is something like that, at django backend
/accounts/id/uuid:pk/some_action/

in the models it is defined as

```
id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
```

The apiview accepts requests and pk which is uuid as pk.

```
@api_view(['PUT'])
def some_action(request, pk):
```

when i'm making a request with uuid it is giving me following error

```
Not Found: /accounts/user/{id}/some-action/
[12/Feb/2022 18:41:28] "PUT /accounts/id/%7Bid%7D/some-action/ HTTP/1.1" 404 4930
```

in Postman i configure the url like this `/accounts/id/{id}/some-action/`

So what might be the problem in passing the uuid ?

Answer (score 0):

Please change the the url in the urls.py to `/accounts/id/<uuid:pk>/some_action/`

Hope it works.

Comment: This is the same as originally I said in the question detail.

Comment: if a manually pass the id inside the url then it works, so probably there is problem in my postman url setup

Comment: For now i'm testing these manualy passing id , but someone if knows better solution should post it

Comment: Please change the the url in the urls.py to /accounts/id/<uuid:pk>/some_action/
I just noticed the url i shared was wrong. 

Please try with this and revert if it works for you